# How to create dialog with uneven edges

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

I need to create a dialog with uneven edges.
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0kd.png)

I tried to set background from drawable resources with that backgroung image.

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false);

    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.aaa);

    return view;
}
```

But the dialog was with a white background.

I'm looking for a solution easier that already exist.

Comment: Did you make changes in the background of dialog layout?

Comment: I put image programmatically in this case. And i tried change background from layout file

Comment: Try setting the background from the xml file. See if it shows the dialog as it should be in the preview.

Comment: And your class name 'Dialog' is a keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code inside the Dialog class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :3. Working. Very simple solution.